# A Collection *OF* DataGridViews? Manipulating all DataGridViews at Once

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I'm continuing to work on a few VSTO's and I was wondering if there was a way to refer to all the datagridviews in a class at once.  I can't seem to figure out what the container should be, and I can't seem to add them to arrays/other containers?

The psudo code for what I'm tring to do would be something like:

```
For Each datagridview in Globals.MyUserControl
   'change some datagridview property ie:
   datagridview1.ReadOnly = True
Next
```

I would be hapy in C# or VB.net, or really any explanation of if this can or can't be done.  At the moment I'm manually setting it for all the different datagridviews, as that number grows, I would like a way to hit them all at once.

Still trying to work on the solutions below, another way I've tried this that doesn't work:

```
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is DataGridView Then
            ctl.ReadOnly = True
            ctl.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
        End If
    Next
```

But I don't know why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)()
        ctl.ReadOnly = True
        ctl.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    Next
```

Or C#

```
        foreach (DataGridView ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
        {
            ctrl.ReadOnly = true;
            ctrl.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        }
```

This loops through only the DataGridViews in the form.

Additionally you can add them to a List(Of DataGridView), if necessary

Another option is to declare a class that inherits DataGridView, set the properties you want, and declare new datagridviews of this type to add to your form(s).

Comment: This compiles, but doesn't actually do anything.  If you add `MsgBox(ctl.Name)` you will note nothing comes up, so I'm guessing even if I put this in the User Control, adding Me.Controls is not getting the datagridviews (seems to get tab controls, etc)

Comment: Then the DatGridView's aren't in the form your calling this from.  Declare a  class level list then in each forms constructor add any DGV's to the list.  Now from any form you should be able to set their properties.  In C# you will probably have to change the modifier of each DGV to public first.

Comment: Yep, they are all nested in a tab control which was in the form I was calling.  Sorry thought it would be recursive.

Comment: Change the Me or this to the name of the tabcontrol.  If necessary you may have to loop through each tabpage as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a foreach loop:

```
foreach (DataGridView ctrl in Globals.MyUserControl.Controls)
    ctrl.ReadOnly = true;
```

If you're expecting any non-datagridview controls in the controls collection that you don't want to set to read-only, then instead of a single statement, you can check the type of ctrl.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Globals.MyUserControl.Controls)
    if(ctrl is DataGridView) ctrl.ReadOnly = true;
```

Using LINQ, you can do this:

```
Globals.MyUserControl.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToList().ForEach((ctrl) => { if (ctrl is DataGridView) ((DataGridView)ctrl).ReadOnly = true; });
```

Or if all your controls are known to be DataGridView controls, then you can do this:

```
Globals.MyUserControl.Controls.Cast<DataGridView>().ToList().ForEach(ctrl => ctrl.ReadOnly = true);
```

To find child controls inside other controls, define a recursive method and call that:

```
    private static void FindControlsRecursively(Control.ControlCollection collection)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in collection)
        {
            if (ctrl is DataGridView)
                ((Label)ctrl).ReadOnly = true;
            else if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
                FindControlsRecursively(ctrl.Controls);
        }
    }
```

Then call it with the controls of your user control from your user control:

```
FindControlsRecursively(this.Controls);
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time accessing ToList of my UserControl or any windows form for that matter?  I got when I made an arbitrary list.  I also can't seem to add datagridviews to a list?

Comment: Sorry, should be MyUserControl.Controls. Editing code shortly.

Comment: The UserForms and UserControls don't seem to have a reference/definition for Controls.  There is ControlCollection but it doesn't contain ToList?

Comment: Aaah, my bad. I always forget that some collections in the framework do not have the ForEach extension. Updating with a simple foreach loop instead. :(

Comment: If the Globals.MyUserControl collection implements IEnumerable rather than IEnumerable<T> then you just need to call .Cast<T> where T is the narrowest type that covers every type in the array before using linq to convert it into an IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: Thanks, @user1937198. Updated answer to use that, too.

Comment: I still don't have a reference/definition in MyUserControl.Controls? (I have both a C# and VB project I'm trying to work this into).  In the VB I can get Me.Controls.etc.. but it's not actually working (compiles, just doesn't seem to effect anything)

Comment: What is the type of MyUserControl?

Comment: Visual C#/VB Items Window Forms User Control

Comment: Looking at your other comment to tinstaafl's answer, it looks like your DataGridViews are not the child of the user control but other controls inside the user control, like a tab control. So I would suggest a recursively. I am adding an edit as such, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I should put this in the answer, or if Tombola wants to move it to his, but here was my solution.  The problem was that all my datagridviews were nested on tab pages in a tab control.  To get it to work I used:

```
    For Each tabpg In TabControl1.TabPages()
        For Each ctl In tabpg.Controls  'note, was not able to use 'OfType here, but had to drop to the If statement or I ran into runtime errors.
            If TypeOf ctl Is DataGridView Then
                ctl.ReadOnly = True
                ctl.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
            End If
        Next
    Next
```